# Functions chain with delays in swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, queue, chain

I'm wondering how it is possible to chain a sequence of `UIView.animationWithDuration:completion:` functions to perform each next function from completion closure of previous animationWithDuration. So I should have something like:

```
finalAnimation <<< animationB <<< animationA <<< initialValues()
```

It's easy to chain them if functions doesn't have any time delay inside. Also it's easy to build a queue of animations with a shared object that contains queue items. But it's not clear how to build such queue without sharing anything but just chaining `animationWithDuration:completion:`
Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

You can not chain with animation, chaining requires the function to return optional type `fun1()?.func2()?.func3()` . This is not achievable since animateWithDuraion: return immediately. You can use dispatch_semaphore to wait for completion block but it is not recommended since your animation should not not block the main thread

here is my suggestion:

you can do something like this

```
func myAnimation(duration: NSTimeInterval, animation:() -> Void, onFinish: () -> Void) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
        animation()
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        onFinish()
    }
}
```

and then

```
myAnimation(0.0, { animation in

        }) { completion in

        myAnimation(0.0, { animation in

        }, { completion in
            myAnimation(0.0, { animation in

            }, { completion in

            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: it's equal to animateWithDuration and doesn't. I can simply chain animateWithDuration in the same way.

Comment: do you want to do custom animation inside ? if so then we can implement it differently ?

Comment: No. I want function chains. Take a look at my question. I have added code example how it should looks like

Comment: just updated my question, you need to return something to make the changing

Answer (score 1):

I came across this library which might be interesting for you. It has a section in its documentation about chaining animations.

https://github.com/MengTo/Spring

Comment: Unfortunately. This library doesn't use function chains with functions that has a delay. [link]https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=animatewithduration[/link]
I have looked through github. This is the first I have done. But no luck to find something that can work for me.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T nest animations. What you want is [animateKeyframesWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:), which allows you to chain animations together in a much cleaner way.

See also http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/01/stop-nesting-animation-blocks/

Comment: what if I don't want to calculate StartTime? I want to plug animations one inside other just like a unix pipe

Comment: Pass in a start time of 0 to start the animations immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @NRitH that keyframe animations are a good way to go.

Another option is to write a method that calls itself from the completion handler. Something like this:

```
var step = 3;

func animate()
{
  UIView.animateWithDuration: 1.0,
    delay: 1.0,
    options: 0,
    animations: ^
    {
       switch step:
       {
         case 3:
           //1st animation
         case 2:
           //2nd animation
         case 1:
           //3rd animation
         default:
           //we're done
       }
    },
    completion: ^
    {
      (finished) in
      step--
      if finished && step > 0
      {
         animate()
      }
    }
}
```

(Syntax may not be perfect. I've been working in Objective-C for the past month or so so my Swift has gotten a tad rusty.)

### EDIT:

I just realized that you wanted to add delay between the animations. I edited my code to show how to do that.

I put in a fixed delay of 1 second between steps. If you want variable delay, you'd need to create an array of delay values.